# Ethereum web3 Browser Only functions

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

Two of the functions of web3
 -  web3.eth.accounts.wallet.load
 -  web3.eth.accounts.wallet.save

Mentioned in the Doc of web3, these are browser only functions. Already tried to test these function by using IPC as well as RPC calls but both failed saying "**load is not a function/save is not a function**"
How and where i can run these functions to check their functionality and what does "browser only" means?

Comment: Don't know anything about web3 & browsers, but `web3.eth.accounts` runs asynchronously. So I suggest that you start with this function, see what you get back, and then proceed from there (I know I get back a promise which returns an array of accounts when resolved).

Comment: yes the return is already an array with accounts, but on calling save or load functions it returns error .